# How to avoid throwing into the URL stuff I don't want for a form with GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form tag:

```
= form_tag entities_path, method: :get do
  = select(....)
  = select(....)
  = button_to "Search", name: nil
```

When I click a button, it puts into the url many things I don't want such as authenticity_token and utf-8. How can I avoid that? I only want 2 selects and their values in the url.

Comment: Why are you getting the values in the url, just use the post method

Answer (score 0):

These attributes [can be disabled](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag):

```
= form_tag entities_path, method: :get, authenticity_token: false, enforce_utf8: false do
  = select(....)
  = select(....)
  = button_to "Search", name: nil
```

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: the same as before